# Real Time Notifications in django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a few types of notifications in my django project and as of now they are worked out using signals and the notifications are displaying correctly but it is not made real time. What is the best way to implement real time notifications in django?I have done a messaging app with django channels.Is django channels the best way to proceed?

Comment: A "what is the best" question is probably off-topic here as it invites opinion-based answers - and asking for off-site resource recommendation is frowned upon as well. That said, [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and web sockets are the best option IMHO.

Comment: ok Thanks @PauloScardine

Comment: yes - thats the best way

Comment: Yes, you can use Django Channels for the real-time notification. In future, most of the channels codebase will be migrated to Django itself. https://www.aeracode.org/2018/06/04/django-async-roadmap/